# Use Python f-strings and Jinja at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I am trying to write a concise SQL query string in Python, to make use of both f-strings and Jinja at the same time.
*Background info: I am writing a query used in Airflow.*

This did not work:

```
query_string = f"""
        SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT case_id) AS counts
        FROM
            `{{var.value.gcp_project}}.{{var.value.dataset_prefix}}user.person`
        WHERE
            identified_on = PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '{YESTERDAY_DATE_STR}')
           """
```

It produced the query string as:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT case_id) AS counts
FROM
    `{var.value.gcp_project}.{var.value.dataset_prefix}user.person`
WHERE
    identified_on = PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2020-09-07')
```

So it did the f-string value replacement but not the Jinja.

How can I make both f-strings and Jinja work at the same time?

Answer (score 21):

I found that doubling the curly brackets `{{` and `}}` works.
The double curly bracket gets escaped to a single one, and since Jinja requires 2 of them, 4 brackets does the trick.

So this query:

```
query_string = f"""
        SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT case_id) AS counts
        FROM
            `{{{{var.value.gcp_project}}}}.{{{{var.value.dataset_prefix}}}}user.person`
        WHERE
            identified_on = PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '{YESTERDAY_DATE_STR}')
           """
```

Returns a correctly formatted query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT case_id) AS counts
FROM
    `gcp_project.dataset_user.person`
WHERE
    identified_on = PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2020-09-07')
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is more elegant to instead use the good old `%` operator here, which helps to avoid the confusion raised because of similar `{` notations.

Here, the jinja-template string is clear and unambiguous:

```py
query_string = """
        SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT case_id) AS counts
        FROM
            `{{var.value.gcp_project}}.{{var.value.dataset_prefix}}user.person`
        WHERE
            identified_on = PARSE_DATE('%%Y-%%m-%%d', '%s')
           """ % (YESTERDAY_DATE_STR)
```

->

```sql
        SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT case_id) AS counts
        FROM
            `{{var.value.gcp_project}}.{{var.value.dataset_prefix}}user.person`
        WHERE
            identified_on = PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '2020-09-07')
```

In your case, you still need to escape the date parser parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna use the `format` method instead, so that you can avoid the escaping for `{`:

```py
query_string = "
        SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT case_id) AS counts
        FROM
            `{gcp_project}.{dataset_prefix}user.person`
        WHERE
            identified_on = PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', '{yesterday}')
           ".format(**var.value, yesterday=YESTERDAY_DATE_STR)
```